# How to use the gitlab merge request as a npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab

Consider that there are two npm projects, package-a and package-b, which are hosted in a private gitlab instance. package-a depends on package-b via git+ssh protocol.

Now as an engineer I need to modify some code in package-b. Before I merge my change to the trunk branch, I hope that I can test my change with package-a to avoid unexpected bugs. How can I let package-a use the package-b that contain the un-merged changes?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab provides a corresponding `refs/merge-requests/$iid/merge` for the merge result of the merge, which could be used for this purpose.

Let's say, your merge request id in project-b is 106, then you can run the following command in the project-a to test with your merge request

`npm install 'git+ssh://git@git.yourcompany.com:products/package-b.git#merge-requests/106/merge'`

More reading: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/47110